# Eclipse Data Source Explorer MIssing Connection Profiles

Tags: eclipse

Not sure when they went missing but I had a half dozen connection profiles under Database Connections in the Data Source Explorer that are not being listed now.  Is there a way to recover them, for example by going into the workspace .metadata files/folders?  Or do I have to manual enter them all again.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the connection profiles still exist they will be found in the workspace XML file

> **{workspace path}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity\driverStorage.xml**.

Your problem is unusual, so the first step should be to check Eclipse's **Error Log**. If there is nothing useful there then:

1. If **driverStorage.xml** exists but does not contain the connection profiles then:

   - Perhaps you could possibly recover them from a backup of your workspace?
   - Otherwise, since the data is specific to a workspace, if you happen to have those connection profiles also defined for another workspace you could copy the definitions from the **driverStorage.xml** file for that workspace.
   - If those two options don't apply the you would just have to re-enter the data.
2. If the connection profiles do exist in **driverStorage.xml** then:

   - The problem is (at a minimum) that the data is not being rendered in the IDE, and you could try restarting Eclipse with the **-clean** parameter. That smacks of desperation a bit, but it can't do any harm, and it might solve the problem if there is an issue with the metadata.
   - If that doesn't work then something strange is going on. Pehaps create a new workspace?
3. If **driverStorage.xml** does not exist for that workspace then:

   - If **driverStorage.xml** exists somewhere else (another workspace or a backup) then try copying that file to your workspace.
   - Otherwise you will have to re-enter the connection profile data.

None of those three options seems very likely, but one of them has to be true.

As an aside, I was surprised to see that the database users/passwords that were specified when setting up the DB connection are stored in **driverStorage.xml** as raw text!

Comment: I didn't see your post before I started manually recreating my database connection profiles.  However, the driverStorage.xml did not contain the few newly connection profiles that I assumed I would see according to your post. Are you sure we are talking about the same thing?  Or perhaps my version of Eclipse (Neon) uses a different location.